# Strange behaviour with NavigationBar

Tags: iphone

I'm having some really strange behavior with the NavigationBar and I'm hoping someone has seen something like this before.

[image: screenshot of the situation]

I have a UIView that is being pushed with

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cardView animated:NO];
```

and immediately when the view is pushed I get the result that can be seen in the first half of the picture above.

When I click a button that pushes a modalview controller and I then return to the original view (with a simple dismiss) I get what can be seen in the second half of the picture.

When the view first loads it appears it does not account for the height of the navigation bar and puts it beneath the bar. Yet the view is larger in interface builder so it does adjust it's size according to the bars, but still puts itself beneath them.

When returning from the modalview it has just pushed everything down the right amount of pixels for everything to be visible.

It's as if something forces it to be at window origin 0,0 when first loading and then when returning from the modalview it fixes itself.

I don't even know where to begin looking for the problem on this one.

Edit: I just discovered that if I set animated:YES in the above code it puts it in the right position *after* it has slid in the view.

Comment: Maybe you set the frame of the view somewhere after the view appears ? In an other case, please provide some code, where you initialize the view "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

at the start of viewDidLoad. This caused it to somehow reset and move the view. I can't really see an animation going on though. I think the root of the problem might lie in the fact that I'm switching from portrait mode to landscape mode and that somehow messes with the bar.